# SQL Server JSON array foreign key values using join

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-server-2016

Below is schema of the data stored in SQL Server 2016 Database

```
+------------+-------------+
| CountryKey | CountryName |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 | USA         |
|          2 | Japan       |
|          3 | China       |
|          4 | UK          |
|          5 | Australia   |
+------------+-------------+
```

And in the Store table the information is saved as JSON

```
+-------+-----------+
| Store | Countries |
+-------+-----------+
| A     | [1,2]     |
| B     | [1,3]     |
| C     | [1,3,4]   |
| D     | [4,5]     |
| E     | [1,5]     |
+-------+-----------+
```

This design is working fine when I want to filter data, for example I'm able to use [OPEN_JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to filter the stores based on `CountryKey`

But after filter - the requirement is to show `Country Name` instead of Country Key as shown below -

**Desired Output**

```
+-------+----------------+
| Store | CountriesName  |
+-------+----------------+
| A     | USA, Japan     |
| B     | USA, China     |
| C     | USA, China, UK |
| D     | UK, Asutralia  |
| E     | USA, Australia |
+-------+----------------+
```

**My Question** is can this be achieved with `SQL Query` or need to process data with server side language e.g `C#`.
If yes syntax and references will help.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest fixing the design to a normalised approach. Not only do you need to split the data here, you then want to rebuild it into a comma separated list.

Comment: But the advantage of using JSON in SQL server 2016 will be gone.
I need this tabular information only for report.

Comment: Storing relational data is not what you're meant to be using JSON data in SQL server for though. That should be in normalised tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to parse the country code with `OPENJSON()`, use appropriate join and aggregate the country names. For SQL Server 2016 you need to use `FOR XML PATH` for string aggregation:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Country (
   CountryKey int,
   CountryName nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Country 
   (CountryKey, CountryName)
VALUES
   (1, N'USA'),
   (2, N'Japan'),   
   (3, N'China'),   
   (4, N'UK'),      
   (5, N'Australia')
CREATE TABLE Store (
   Store nvarchar(1),
   Countries nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Store
   (Store, Countries)
VALUES   
   (N'A', N'[1,2]'),
   (N'B', N'[1,3]'),
   (N'C', N'[1,3,4]'),
   (N'D', N'[4,5]'),
   (N'E', N'[1,5]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT s.Store, STUFF(t.Country, 1, 2, N'') AS Country
FROM Store s
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT ', ' + c.CountryName
   FROM OPENJSON(s.Countries) WITH (CountryKey int '$') j
   LEFT JOIN Country c ON c.CountryKey = j.CountryKey
   FOR XML PATH('')
) t (Country)
```

Result:

```
Store   Country
A       USA, Japan
B       USA, China
C       USA, China, UK
D       UK, Australia
E       USA, Australia
```

If you can upgrade to SQL Server 2017, string aggregation can be done using `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT s.Store, t.Country
FROM Store s
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT STRING_AGG(c.CountryName, N', ')
   FROM OPENJSON(s.Countries) WITH (CountryKey int '$') j
   LEFT JOIN Country c ON c.CountryKey = j.CountryKey
) t (Country)
```

Comment: Great this is exactly the same output, I was looking for